# What feature do I need to enable to see Question-Question Layout or Reply-Reply Layout?

Tags: metadata-api, page-layout, metadata

I'm having a bit of trouble recreating this and I'm not sure where to look. One of the orgs I performed the metadata API retrieve on has a couple layouts called Reply-Reply Layout.layout and Question-Question Layout.layout however I can't seem to find out how to recreate getting these layouts on another org I have.

Does anyone know what I need to enable to be able to see these layouts?

Comment: Also running into this issue